# Html popup that opens a link and a image file beside it automatically?

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, popup

Is it possible to have a popup code that opens a link and an image beside it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with javascript you can say: when clicked on this object, open a new window (or 2) with this as content (u can put an ing in it or even a link to an other website.)

I hope this helped. (for actual code you can easily find it on multiple websites if you use words like new window, blanc window, …)